# How to automate cleanup of config files from past pkgs as reported by "dpkg -l | grep ^rc"

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, configuration-management, dpkg

There are a number of pkgs that weren't removed with "apt-get purge" and I would like to automate cleaning them up.

You can't `apt-get purge apache2.2-common` because the pkg is already removed.

You can still list the files that are in the pkg with `dpkg -L apache2.2-common`.

This means I could just remove the list of files in the pkg, but how would dpkg know this?  How do I remove the config files left behind AND remove it from the following report?

Example output:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ^rc
rc  apache2.2-common                  2.2.14-5ubuntu8.10                Apache HTTP Server common files
rc  libapache2-mod-php5filter         5.3.10-1ubuntu2ppa6~lucid         server-side, HTML-embedded scripting languag
rc  libapr1                           1.3.8-1ubuntu0.3                  The Apache Portable Runtime Library
rc  libaprutil1                       1.3.9+dfsg-3ubuntu0.10.04.1       The Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library
rc  libgd2-xpm                        2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-3.1ubuntu1        GD Graphics Library version 2
rc  libt1-5                           5.1.2-3ubuntu0.10.04.2            Type 1 font rasterizer library - runtime
rc  php5-gd                           5.3.10-1ubuntu2ppa6~lucid         GD module for php5
rc  ssl-cert                          1.0.23ubuntu2                     simple debconf wrapper for OpenSSL
```

Comment: I probably do /not/ want to remove ssl-cert. It is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will find the package names:

```
dpkg --list | grep ^rc | awk '{print $2}'
```

Or to remove the number of pipes you can use this:

```
dpkg --list | awk '/^rc/ {print $2}'
```

So the next step is to feed one of those lists into `dpkg --purge`.  Using a subshell you can do that easily:

```
dpkg --purge $(dpkg --list | grep ^rc | awk '{print $2}')
```

Simple!

Comment: Ah, I tried various iterations of `dpkg | awk | xargs apt-get purge` which was failing because the pkg was not installed.  I never tried `dpkg | awk | xargs dpkg --purge`.  To be honest, I didn't know it had a purge option.  Thank you!